# Table doesn't show

Tags: tables, apa6

I am using the following code but the table doesn't show up:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
As usual the text....bla bla bla...

I use a .tex directory to create a table using the following commands:
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Tail Dependence.}
\label{Tails}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}\\ \toprule
bla bla bla... \\ \midrule
bla& bla &bla&bla &bla &bla &bla &bla &bla 
&bla &bla &bla   &bla\\
bla&bla&bla &bla &bla &bla &bla &bla &bla &bla & &bla    &bla\tnote{***}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item[\tnote{***}] If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq$ \textit{Pr}[1\%].
\item[\tnote{**}] If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq$ \textit{Pr}[5\%].
\end{tablenotes}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I get this 
[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Where is the \end{document} ?

Comment: done it!!! I forgot to posted here in the code I have it. sorry

Comment: The use of the `\tnote` "wrapper" inside the optional argument of \item is wrong. Please, please write `\item[***]` and `\item[**]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

removing `adjustbox` (see [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) answer), adding missing packages your tabvle works as expected. to fit table into text width i suggest to use `tabular*` environment and left to `latex` that determine `\tabcol` size:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
As usual the text....bla bla bla...

I use a .tex directory to create a table using the following commands:
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Tail Dependence.}
\label{Tails}
%\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}  % don't use it! it is cause of your troubles ...
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             *{13}{c}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{13}{l}{bla bla bla \dots}              \\
    \midrule
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla
    & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla             \\
bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla
    & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla & bla\tnote{***}  \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}
\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize%\small
\item[***] If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[1\%]$,
\item[**]  If $\lambda_{L}$ or $\lambda_{U} \geq \mathit{Pr}[5\%]$.
\end{tablenotes}
%\end{adjustbox}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]
(red lines indicate text border)

Comment: @Mico, ups, i overlooked this ... corrected! thank you very much!

Comment: I used your suggestions, initially worked but as I added numbers insted of "bla" and more rows the table won't fit? any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, i haven't crystal ball to see, what you doing with this table. you should show us, what numbers you have (how many digits they have), if you change number of column or if the table has so many numbers that it can't be fit on one page. in this case you should consider `longtable` or similar tables' environments. there exist many possibilities for solving your problem, however, we need more information about this. the best would be, if you ask new question where provide mwe, which will show your problem.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/threeparttable.pdf) of `threeparttable`:

> Inside a `threeparttable` there should be a caption, followed by a
>   `tabular` environment (`tabular`, `tabular*`, `tabularx` or the like),
>   possibly followed by a series of itemized tablenotes. (The caption may
>   also go after the tabular environment.)

Therefore, the `tabular` cannot be hidden inside environment `adjustbox`.

Comment: So the order of threeparttable, tabular and adjustbox is wrong?

Comment: @WilmerRojas - The use of `adjustbox`, *in and by itself*, is wrong, in the sense that it messes up `threeparttable`'s operations. It's not a matter of ordering of the environments.

Comment: @mico if i don't use adjustbox the table goes beyond the margins and part of the table can't be seen!!!

Comment: @WilmerRojas You can try a smaller font `\small`. But the table has many columns (13) and is likely too large for the text width. Try setting the table in landscape or reorganize the table. Scaling the table down by a large factor is not a good solution.